# Create Contact in Phone from WebView html - Android App

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to add a contact (only mobile number) to the phone from WebView HTML page?

Any pointers would be quite helpful.

Comment: Did you go through the link I edited in my answer? For contacts..

Comment: @user370305 yes.. but couldn't find the code to add a contact.. or am I missing something??

Comment: Ohh..Sorry, my mistake, I edited the links please go through these..

Answer (score 1):

I think **its possible**, (But never try this)..

1. Load your webpage in android webview in that make a javascript which is fetch the mobile number from the HTML page.
2. Make a Android function to add a mobile number in contact and call that function from java script.

Use Java Script interface for calling Android function from JAVA Script.

TO communicate between Java Script and Android function look at this example [Android WebView](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-webview.html) Also [Android WebView, Javascript and CSS](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html)

**EDIT:** Look at this tutorial for how to add contacts in android [Contacts API 2.0 and above | Android Developer Tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/05/contacts-api-20-and-above-android.html)  and [Android How-To: Create a new Contact](http://www.lacherstorfer.at/haris_blog/2008/03/android-howto-create-a-new-con.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response..

I know how to communicate between Javascript and Android Webview.. I just want to know how to add a contact to the phone?

Comment: @Peter: if you are looking for **code** to create phonebook entry, Googling will give you lots of tutorials, examples and even fully working project source codes.

Comment: @SarwarErfan Thanks.. I've already Googled but couldn't find appropriate working code :( 

This is the code that I use,

`ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
     values.put(People.NAME, name); 
     Uri uri = CoreLib.ContentResolver().insert(People.CONTENT_URI, values); 
     Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, 
     People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY); 
     values.clear(); 
     values.put(People.Phones.TYPE, People.Phones.TYPE_MOBILE); 
     values.put(People.Phones.NUMBER, mobile); 
     CoreLib.ContentResolver().insert(phoneUri, values);`

but it didnt work as well :(

Answer (score 1):

Put this in html page where you want user to click to create phonebook entry:

```
<a href="wtai://wp/ap;5551234;My Name">Add 5551234  to phonebook</a>
```

When this page is loaded in WebView or browser and user clicks on the link, new phonebook entry screen will appear.

It will work on almost any phone.

I have put the html in [a test web page](http://insidebd.com/wtai.htm). Visit from your mobile to test.

To know more about the protocol, read [this](http://mobile.kaywa.com/files/WAP-170-WTAI-20000707-a.pdf)

Comment: I tried your code in my html file. When I click on the link it says that _Webpage not available. The webpage at wtai://wp/ap;5551234;My %20Name might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web adress_

I also tried you test web page in my mobile browser, but it didnt work :(